# Declaring a pointer in MIPS

Tags: mips

Just starting out in mips and having a little trouble with one concept. Let's say I want to take this and put it into mips

```
char *number = "one";
```

How would I implement that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the variable in the .data section

```
number: .asciiz "one"
```

and if you want the base address of it you store it in $t0 with a load address instruction

```
la $t0, number
```

and you can load the word, byte, or halfword into $t1 with a load instruction like this

```
lw $t1, 0($t0)
```

where the 0 is the offset from the base address